# How to optimize socket broadcasting to clients?

Tags: sockets, socket.io, angular7, mean-stack

The server now is sending a broadcast message to all connected clients (chat system), the problem is how to optimize the broadcast to be recognized only with one client,

Currently server is broadcasting the message to all client. I tried to make a secret to be send from server and decryption/checking on client side but I don't believe it's the optimal

On the server side I have this:

```
//server
io.on('connection', function(socket: any) {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('chat-message', function(message: any) {
    console.log(message);
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat-message-server', message);
  });
```

On the client side I have this:

```
//client
ngOnInit() {
  socket.emit('chat-message', 'chat-message-server', '123');
}

this.socket.on('chat-message-server', data => {
  console.log('chat-message-server--->' + data);
});
```

I expect to receive this message on a single receiver rather than checking if (userId == IncomingUserId) on every single client.

Comment: I'm thinking to add the desired receiver function as a parameter to be sent by sender, so server in this case will do socket.to(FunName).emit('message...')

Comment: If you think my response has answered your question, then consider marking it as accepted for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 0):

`io.to().emit()` can be used to send data only to the desired client instead of broadcasting to all clients.

**Server:**

```
// Sending to individual socketId (private message).
io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('eventName', 'data);
```

Here, server sends data only to the client identified by the `socketId`.

You mentioned in your comment about having the client send `senderName`. You can instead have them send their `socketId` and then use this method on the server to  send data to just that client.

**Client:**

```
socket.on('eventName', data => {
  // Do something.
}
```

Check out [socket.io emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/) for all possible options to send data.

Comment: io.on('connection', function(socket: any) {
      socket.on('chat-message', function(senderName, message) {
        socket.broadcast.emit(senderName, message);
      });

      socket.on('chat-disconnected', function(senderName, message) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', message);
      });
    });


I guess in this case is kind of optimal one, using senderName as function name and having on client side :

Comment: No, this is not optimal. You are still using `socket.broadcast.emit()` which sends it to all clients except the sender. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Having on server side

```
io.on('connection', function(socket: any) {
      socket.on('chat-message', function(senderName, message) {
        socket.broadcast.emit(senderName, message);
      });

      socket.on('chat-disconnected', function(senderName, message) {
        socket.broadcast.emit('disconnected', message);
      });
    });
```

I guess in this case is kind of optimal one, using `senderName` as function name and having on client side

```
 this.socket.on('chat-data', data => {
      // do stuff
    });

    this.socket.on('disconnected', data => {
      // change the status
    });
```

Comment: No, this is not optimal. You are still using `socket.broadcast.emit()` which sends it to all clients except the sender. Check out my answer where you can just send it to your desired client.